# d3.js Line Chart -> dont get it zooming

Tags: d3.js, zoom-sdk

i try to make a d3.js chart zooming. i got it that the zoom function i called, but i do not really know how to redraw the chart.
i used some examples but they are all very different to my chart.

Maybe someone could help me, or give me a hint.

in first step i just want to zoom the X axis.

i have uploaded my try to plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pda3qnIFFF4V0kF5)

```html
function zoomed() {
    console.log('zoom');
      //var t = d3.event.transform;
      //x.domain(t.rescaleX(x).domain());
      //Line_chart.select(".line").attr("d", line);
      //focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
    x.range([margin.left, width - margin.right]
                .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));

            theChart.select(".path")
                .attr("d", line);

            theChart.select(".x-axis")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
                    .tickSizeOuter(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors. See it fixed in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8u9nTtXTB7qPMtCc)

Fix the d3 zoom initialization:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, Infinity]).on("zoom", () => zoomed(theChart));
```

Fix zoomed callback:

```
const zoomed = chart =>  chart.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
```

Comment: Thank you Michael,

but now the whole chart is zooming (and moving). 
How can i achieve that the x and y axis are fixed (dont move) and just the x-Axis scale is changend?
like this example: [link](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/7ac1d41fe75fe7d2d9cb85e78aad6303)

Comment: Put under one <g> the content you want to zoom, and under another <g> the content you want to stay in place. In 'zoomed' callback, apply trasform only to the first <g> element

Comment: i think i dont know how to do it, there are so much variables and functions

i tried it with following code: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sxs3TvWaJ8GkTRA4)

Comment: can you help me please?